# What is the most efficient way to search WooCommerce database for products by unique ID and check if product exists or not?

Tags: php, database, wordpress, woocommerce

Suppose you work with a 20,000 product database and you need to check if a product with each unique ID exists in the database or not. Rather than loading 20,000 products in PHP memory, what is another way to check?

Can you load the 20,000 products in batches of 1000 products and check without having the memory explode?

In other words, how can I get the first 5000 products out of 20,000, then load the next 5,000, and then the next?

Is there a way to batch?

Comment: What's wrong with loading that many products into PHP's memory? I assume this is not happening on every page load, right? One-time maintenance sort of deal? Your best bet is to learn how to do this natively in presumably MySQL for your situation. Without knowing what you have tried and failed on it is nearly impossible to provide a useful answer.

Comment: This process has to happen hourly. It is a custom PHP program to connect an API of a stock management system to an eshop. I need every hour to check if products stock has changed and update it. I need to find a way to get 5000 out of 20000 products first, then get the other 5000, then the other 5000.. Like in 4 batches.. Any ideas?

Comment: Those kinds of details are rather important don't you think? Why are they not a part of your question...

Comment: And, yes, there are plenty of ways to batch jobs but 20,000 items is honestly not a lot for PHP to handle in one shot assuming they're just product IDs. You should fetch your products from the DB and per-product connect to the API and get a fresh stock count and update your DB. Assuming you do this in a loop then the memory should be relatively stable. You are going to find that your choke point is the API since it is a network-based interaction. If the API can accept multiple IDs at once then you should take advantage of that.